# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{945}$ by Fourier series of $x^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

> Prove that
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{945}$$ by the Fourier series of $x^2$.

By Parseval's identity, I can only show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$. Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: I think you need to use the fourier series of x^3 to directly use Parseval's identity.

Comment: ... or integrate the Fourier series of $x^2$, *then* apply Parseval's theorem. However, in order to implement this idea it is better to take a different quadratic polynomial, namely $B_2\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}\right)$.

Answer (score 4):

We may start from
$$ f_1(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n} \tag{1}$$
that is the Fourier series of a [sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave), equal to $\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ on the interval $I=(0,2\pi)$. 
By termwise integration, we get that
$$ \forall x\in I,\quad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1-\cos(nx)}{n^2} = \frac{2\pi x-x^2}{4}$$
hence:
$$ \forall x\in I,\quad f_2(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\pi x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{4}\tag{2} $$
$$ \forall x\in I,\quad f_3(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^3}=\frac{\pi^2 x}{6}-\frac{\pi x^2}{4}+\frac{x^3}{12}\tag{3} $$
(the integration constants are computed from the fact that $f_j(x)$ has to have mean zero over $I$)
 and by [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem)
$$ \zeta(6) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f_3(x)^2\,dx = \frac{2\pi^6}{9}\int_{0}^{1}\left[x(x-1)(2x-1)\right]^2\,dx=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^6}{945}}.\tag{4}$$
With the same approach it is not difficult to prove that for any $n\geq 1$, $\zeta(2n)$ is a rational multiple of $\pi^{2n}\int_{0}^{1}B_n(x)^2\,dx$, where $B_n(x)$ is a [Bernoulli polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials).

Comment: it is not 100% clear that you substract the mean such that $f_j(x)$ has zero mean

Comment: @user1952009: the expression for $f_2(x)$ is derived from $f_2(x)=\zeta(2)-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1-\cos(nx)}{n^2}$ and the expression for $f_3(x)$ is derived from $f_3(\pi)=0$. Anyway, answer improved. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: But where is the Fourier series of $x^2$?

Comment: @Longitude: it is part of $(2)$. See my comment under your question.

Answer (score 4):

Considering $f(x)=x^3$ By Parseval identity we can prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{945}$.
Then $$a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx=0,$$$$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)dx=0$$ and \begin{align}b_n&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)dx\\&=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2\pi^2}{n}+(-1)^{n}\frac{12\pi}{n^3}\end{align}
From the relation $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f|^2dx=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n^2+b_n^2)$$we get \begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{144}{n^6}+\frac{4\pi^4}{n^2}-\frac{48\pi^2}{n^4})=\frac{2\pi^6}{7}\end{align}$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{144}{n^6}=\frac{16\pi^6}{105}$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{945}$$